# Plotting graphs lines based on column values from the same datafram using Plotly

Tags: r, dplyr, plotly

I am trying to plot a line graph of different types of cars sold per day in ** plotly ** on ** R **. The way the graph would look is that, it would have line graphs of each type of car that was sold on each day. So lets say I have the dataframe called ** df1 **

```
id      date       Value 
Honda    10/30/12   2
Honda    10/31/12   3
Honda    11/1/12    3
Merc     11/2/12    4
Merc    10/30/12    1
Merc    10/31/12    2
Toyota   11/1/12    3
Toyota   11/3/12    2
```

Now I want three lines(one line for each type of car) on the same x axis.

I tried using the `filter()` function inside plotly in the `y axis` argument as shown below:

```r
plot_ly(df1,x=~date)%>% 
add_trace(y=filter(df1,id=="Honda")$value,name="Honda",mode="lines+markers")%>%
add_trace(y=filter(df1,id=="Merc")$value,name="Honda",mode="lines+markers")%>%
add_trace(y=filter(df1,id=="Toyota")$value,name="Honda",mode="lines+markers")%>%
layout(xaxis=list(title="Date"),yaxis=list(title="Cars Sold"))
```

However I am getting the error

> Error: Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, only values of length one are recycled:
>   * Length 3: Column `y`
>   * Length 8: Column `x`
>   Call `rlang::last_erro()

I get that its throwing an error, due to having more x values while being given less y values, how do I cater it?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the same error (without trace type specified, it drew a histogram).

```
library(plotly)

df1 <- data.frame(
  id = c("Honda", "Honda", "Honda", "Merc", "Merc", "Merc", "Toyota", "Toyota"),
  date = c('10/30/12', '10/31/12', '11/1/12', '11/2/12', '10/30/12', '10/31/12', '11/1/12', '11/3/12'),
  Value = c(2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2)
)

df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date, "%m/%d/%y")

plot_ly(df1,x=~date)%>% 
  add_trace(y=filter(df1,id=="Honda")$value,name="Honda",mode="lines+markers")%>%
  add_trace(y=filter(df1,id=="Merc")$value,name="Honda",mode="lines+markers")%>%
  add_trace(y=filter(df1,id=="Toyota")$value,name="Honda",mode="lines+markers")%>%
  layout(xaxis=list(title="Date"),yaxis=list(title="Cars Sold"))

> plot_ly(df1,x=~date)%>% 
+   add_trace(y=filter(df1,id=="Honda")$value,name="Honda",mode="lines+markers")%>%
+   add_trace(y=filter(df1,id=="Merc")$value,name="Honda",mode="lines+markers")%>%
+   add_trace(y=filter(df1,id=="Toyota")$value,name="Honda",mode="lines+markers")%>%
+   layout(xaxis=list(title="Date"),yaxis=list(title="Cars Sold"))
No trace type specified:
  Based on info supplied, a 'histogram' trace seems appropriate.
  Read more about this trace type -> https://plot.ly/r/reference/#histogram
```

You don't need to filter by each car type. Instead use group_by before calling plot_ly --- perhaps this is what you had in mind:

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  plot_ly(x=~date, y=~Value, type='scatter', color=~id, mode="lines+markers") %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(title="Date"),yaxis=list(title="Cars Sold"))
```

[image: plot of cars sold vs. date using plotly]

Comment: I find that hard to believe considering I even forgot to put the "~" while specifying the y axis values, which would have thrown an error. But regardless it does throw the error above, I retried it. Can you show the code you used where you got no error?

Comment: Also in reply to your answer, Not really, I want the legend to show the different colours for the each type of car. In your code that does not happen, its just showing me the range colours of the values

Comment: see edits - let me know if this is different than what you need in the legend, I'd like to help any way I can.