# Groupby in plotly for a third column not part of x and y axis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby, plotly-python

My dataframe looks like this:

```
df 
node   date   usage
Node1  10/20  2.3
Node1. 10/21  3.4
Node2  10/20  1.9
Node3  10/20  3.3
Node3  10/22  2.4
```

I am looking to plot with x-axis as Date and y-axis as usage but I'd like three line charts in one graph- one for each Node (node is not index). How can I do a groupby in that case?

Here's the code I have for a line chart:

```
data = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=result['date'],
        y=result['usage']).groupby('node')
]

layout=go.Layout(title="CPU Usage per Node per day", xaxis={'title':'date intervals'}, yaxis={'title':'CPU load usage'})
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig)
```

This doesn't group by each Node (One line chart for Node1, one for Node2 etc). I see an example in r, how can I do this in python3?

[Plotting graphs lines based on column values from the same datafram using Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56953875/plotting-graphs-lines-based-on-column-values-from-the-same-datafram-using-plotly)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using the below plotly expression:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig_final = px.bar(df, x="date", y="usage", color="node", title="CPU Usage for Node 1")
fig_final.show()
```